# How to create a folder on BIM 360 though .NET

Tags: .net, post, autodesk-forge, create-directory

I am currently trying to create a folder inside the `Plans` Top Folder with the name "NET folder". Using my method, the program crashes with the output:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The code below is what I am currently using:

```
CreateFolderDataRelationshipsParentData createFolderRelationshipsParentData = new CreateFolderDataRelationshipsParentData(
    "folders",
    parentFolderId);
CreateFolderDataRelationshipsParent createFolderDataRelationshipsParent = new CreateFolderDataRelationshipsParent(createFolderRelationshipsParentData);
CreateFolderDataRelationships createFolderDataFolderRelationships = new CreateFolderDataRelationships(createFolderDataRelationshipsParent);
BaseAttributesExtensionObjectWithoutSchemaLink baseAttribute = new BaseAttributesExtensionObjectWithoutSchemaLink(
    "folders:autodesk.bim360:Folder",
    "1.0",
    folderInfo.Value.attributes.extension.data);
CreateFolderDataAttributes createFolderDataAttributes = new CreateFolderDataAttributes("NET Folder", baseAttribute);
CreateFolderData createFolderData = new CreateFolderData(createFolderDataAttributes, createFolderDataFolderRelationships);
CreateFolder createFolder = new CreateFolder(new JsonApiVersionJsonapi(JsonApiVersionJsonapi.VersionEnum._0), createFolderData);

folderApi.PostFolder(projectId, createFolder);
```

Is there something I am missing to create a folder with the name "NET Folder"?

Comment: Is your parent folder id correct? What is `folderInfo` in your code? Try put `null` to your `BaseAttributes` as the third arg (data) which is optional. Was the 500 thrown by our endpoints or your backend?

Comment: Everything was correct except the object body being passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using the wrong object body inside the `BaseAttributesExtensionObjectWithoutSchemaLink`. Instead of using `folderInfo.Value.attributes.extension.data`, I replaced it with `folder.data` and it worked after.